# Gantt software that is free and simple

Tags: collaboration

I'm looking for a gantt software to use when I'm planning my design projects. Most I've found are expensive once the free trial runs out. Does anyone know what the industry standard is? What does most people use? Do you know of any free ones that are decent? Cheers Lin

Answer (score 1):

A quick look on the world wide interweb shows a MS Project compatible program known as [ProjectLibre](https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/). [The home page](http://www.projectlibre.com/) presents a link for the beta version of the cloud software, but the first link leads to a download page for Windows, Mac and Linux.

There appears to be a number of YouTube videos showing the features and providing for tutorials for this software.

"Industry standard" and "free" are not terms that are commonly used together. Having MS Project compatibility probably gives you the best chance for data exchange/interchange.